# Extract DateTime from a string in R

Tags: r

One of the columns of my data frame have DateTime and some string characters together. LIke:

```
"<13>1 2018-04-18T10:29:00.581243+10:00 KOI-QWE-HUJ vmon 2318 - -  Some Description..."
```

I wish to extract only the DateTime part from it so that I have something like this:

"`2018-04-18 10:29:00.581243"`

I have tried the below:

`as.Date(strptime("<13>1 2018-04-18T10:29:00.581243+10:00 KOI-QWE-HUJ vmon 2318 - -  Some Description...", "Date: %Y-%m-%d"))`
But, this returns NA.

Can anyone please rectify this for me. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I tried the below to get the Date and Time separately. This works but I need to get them together in a column:

### To extract Date:

```
as.Date(str_extract(x, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
> [1] "2018-04-18"
```

### To extract Time:

```
str_extract(x, "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}")
> [1] "10:29:00"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that you should extract the character form of the datetime first. Here is a method that works with that format. It's just using a regular expression and matching 4 digits, then groups of two digits separated by `-`, `T` and `:` where appropriate. You can then use `lubridate::ymd_hms` as an alternative to `as.Date`, since it's a good Swiss army knife at different date formats.

```r
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
string <- "<13>1 2018-04-18T10:29:00.581243+10:00 KOI-QWE-HUJ vmon 2318 - -  Some Description..."
string %>%
  str_extract("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}") %>%
  ymd_hms()
#> [1] "2018-04-18 10:29:00 UTC"
```

Created on 2018-05-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

```
anytime::anytime(sub(".*?\\s(.*?)\\+.*","\\1",a),tz = "UTC",T)
[1] "2018-04-18 10:29:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a string like

> x="extracted date: Dec 14, 2020 10:01PM ET"

The desired output is:

> "2020-12-14 22:01 ET"

I have tried various functions from similar answers to similar questions without success

Thank you